# Slow running query with table with ORDER BY and LIMIT

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-8.0

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    m.id_ AS match_id,
    mv.id_ AS match_version_id,
    t.id_ AS tournament_id
FROM
    test.match_version AS mv
        JOIN
    test.match_ AS m ON m.id_ = mv.match_id
        JOIN
    test.tournament AS t ON t.orig_id = m.tournament_orig_id
        AND t.tour_id = m.tour_id
ORDER BY mv.id_ DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

It is taking around 4 seconds to run where the match tables have circa 1m rows and the tournament table has circa 30k rows. If I remove the `ORDER_BY` then it runs in 0.002 seconds.

Here are the `CREATE TABLE` statements for each table:

```
CREATE TABLE `match_` (
  `id_` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tour_id` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `tournament_orig_id` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_`),
  KEY `ix__match__tour_id` (`tour_id`),
  KEY `ix__match__tour_id__tournament_orig_id` (`tour_id`,`tournament_orig_id`),
  KEY `ix__match__tournament_orig_id` (`tournament_orig_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk__match__tournament` FOREIGN KEY (`tour_id`, `tournament_orig_id`) REFERENCES `tournament` (`tour_id`, `orig_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1666470 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `match_version` (
  `id_` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `match_id` int NOT NULL,
  `generation_start` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `generation_end` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_`),
  KEY `ix__match_version__match_id` (`match_id`),
  KEY `ix__match_version__match_id__generation_end` (`match_id`,`generation_end`),
  KEY `ix__match_version__generation_end` (`generation_end`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk__match_version__match_id` FOREIGN KEY (`match_id`) REFERENCES `match_` (`id_`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1669206 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

CREATE TABLE `tournament` (
  `id_` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tour_id` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `orig_id` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uq__tournament_oc__tour_id__orig_id` (`tour_id`,`orig_id`),
  KEY `ix__tournament_oc__tour_id` (`tour_id`),
  KEY `ix__tournament_oc__orig_id` (`orig_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30962 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Here is the `EXPLAIN` result:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  |                                          possible_keys                                          |                  key                   | key_len |              ref              | rows  | filtered |                    Extra                     |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | NULL       | index | uq__tournament_oc__tour_id__orig_id,ix__tournament_oc__tour_id,ix__tournament_oc__orig_id       | uq__tournament_oc__tour_id__orig_id    |       5 | NULL                          | 30900 |      100 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m     | NULL       | ref   | PRIMARY,ix__match__tour_id,ix__match__tour_id__tournament_orig_id,ix__match__tournament_orig_id | ix__match__tour_id__tournament_orig_id |       5 | test.t.tour_id,test.t.orig_id |    48 |      100 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mv    | NULL       | ref   | ix__match_version__match_id,ix__match_version__match_id__generation_end                         | ix__match_version__match_id            |       4 | test.m.id_                    |     1 |      100 | Using index                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

How come I'm getting considerably poorer performance when the `ORDER_BY` is present? How would I solve this?

Note: Worth mentioning that I know it's not ideal that there is no `tournament_version.tournament_id` foreign key that links to `tournament.id_` but that's sadly what I'm working with atm!

Answer (score 1):

Your query appears to be running into issues with the mysql order by limit slow rate look up. Unfortunately, this is a missing optimization in mysql.

See additional details here to understand why this query is slow. At the bottom of the page, it shows some strategies for how to speed up queries like this: https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/

If that doesn't work you can try to restructure your query to not include both ORDER BY and LIMIT. As you probably noticed from toying with your query, if you can remove either of those keywords, it will be fast again.

Answer (score 0):

I think your indexes are good, but there are some extras you should get rid of.

Since `id_` is the `PRIAMRY KEY`, it is unnecessary and inefficient to start any other index with `id_`.

There are no `WHERE` filtering, so the Optimizer will probably decide to start with an index for the `ORDER BY`, which exists.  This also means that it will stop after 100 rows.  The `EXPLAIN` is not likely to show this stoppage.

A `FOREIGN KEY` is two things:

- An index (which could be constructed via `INDEX` -- equally well)
- A dynamic check in the other table that there is a link.

With ENGINE=InnoDB, the `PRIMARY KEY` is silently tacked on the end of each secondary index.  So it is redundant (optional) to add `id_`  *at the end of*  the above indexes.

Tip.  And this may actually help with performance:

When you have `INDEX(a,b)` (or `UNIQUE(a,b)`), do not also have `INDEX(a)`.  It is redundant, wastes space, and may trick the Optimizer into using the shorter index instead of the composite one.  (I see one such case in each table definition.)

If the `EXPLAIN` fails to list `mv` as the first table, there are multiple ways to force it to be used first.

Comment: Hi Rick. Thanks for this. I removed the two single field indexes from `match_version` and left the dual field version. The Optimizer now picks that one up but performance is the same. `EXPLAIN` is showing table `t` then `m` then `mv`.

Comment: @Jossy Have you tried forcing the join order with `STRAIGHT_JOIN` instead of `JOIN`?

Comment: I hadn't, but I just have and it returned the records in 0.04 seconds!! Thanks a million!! Over to you to post it as an answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @tay_inc for the [link](https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/). This code executes in 0.04 seconds:

```
SELECT 
    m.id_ AS match_id,
    mv.id_ AS match_version_id,
    t.id_ AS tournament_id
FROM
    test.match_version AS mv
        JOIN
    test.match_ AS m ON m.id_ = mv.match_id
        JOIN
    test.tournament AS t ON t.orig_id = m.tournament_orig_id
        AND t.tour_id = m.tour_id
        JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            mv.id_ AS match_version_id
        FROM
            test.match_version AS mv
        ORDER BY mv.id_ DESC
        LIMIT 100
    ) AS o ON o.match_version_id = mv.id_
ORDER BY mv.id_ DESC;
```

The only issue I can see is that this takes the last 100 records in `mv` regardless of whether they can be joined to `m` and `t`. Not an issue for me in this case but worth bearing in mind...

Comment: Caution...  This formulation could return more than 100 tows -- if the `JOINs` are one-to-many.  Or fewer than 100 rows -- if the `JOINs` filter out some of the 100 mv.id_ rows.   _That is, this is not a general solution for similar queries._

Comment: Good shout Rick. Ok in this instance but not in others.